# How to replace words in list with Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I am trying to replace a certain set of words in a list with words from a different list.

1. Check "s"
2. If words in "invalid_list" are in "s" it should be replaced with xyz

The outcome for "s" should be :

['123xyz', '456xyz', '789xyz']

```
s = ['123xyz', '456xye','789xyf']

invalid_list = ['xye','xyf']

for i in invalid_list:
    if i in s:
        s = s.replace(i, 'xyz')
    
print(s)
```

Current (invalid) output:

['123xyz', '456xye', '789xyf']

Comment: `s` is not a string, so the name is confusing. Call it `lst` or something, and then you know you need to iterate the least and replace *each* string in that list.

Comment: You're using `i` for both `for` loops.

Comment: @Barmar: That's the trouble: there is only 1 for loop.

Comment: Oops, I thought the second line was `for i in s`

Comment: Yes, I sometimes see `if i in s` as `for i in s` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over the items of `invalid_list` is inefficient. This increases the complexity of the algorithm.

An efficient solution would be to use a regex to search motifs in each string only once:

```
s = ['123xyz', '456xye','789xyf']

invalid_list = ['xye','xyf']

import re

regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, invalid_list)))

s2 = [regex.sub('xyz', x) for x in s]
```

Output:

```
['123xyz', '456xyz', '789xyz']
```

##### avoid matching partial words:

```
s = ['123xyz', '456xye','789xyf']
invalid_list = ['xy','xye','xyf']
import re
regex = re.compile(f"({'|'.join(map(re.escape, invalid_list))})\b")
s2 = [regex.sub('xyz', x) for x in s]
# ['123xyz', '456xye', '789xyf']
```

Comment: How would it work if you add 'xy' to the invalid list ? You will get 123xyzz as an output.

Comment: @MarcelledeJager it depends how you want to handle it. You can use a word boundary (`\b`) or an end-of-string anchor (`$`) to prevent it if it is unwanted. I added an example.

Comment: I couldn't get the updated one to work with /b, but using $ solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the invalid_list and use the in-built [replace() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/?ref=leftbar-rightbar) to replace the substring.

```
for i in invalid_list:
    s = [string.replace(i, 'xyz') for string in s]
```

Comment: How would it work if you add 'xy' to the invalid list ? You will get 123xyzz as an output.

Comment: The solution proposed was under the impression that all string sizes are the same. You would need a couple of constraints for all the edge cases. Is the format of the strings fixed (i.e. nnnc...c where n is numerical and c is a character)? How many characters can one string have? For instance, '789xyfxyf' would become '789xyzxyz' in this case. Please note down all the edge cases and I can suggest a solution accordingly.

Comment: Please see @mosway solution below. Both lists are a given so giving all cases wont be possible due to the list sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another loop to pull out each string individually, and then your can have your loop to check if any of the invalid strings are there.

Plus you need to reassign the changed string back into the list.

```py
s = ['123xyz', '456xye','789xyf']

invalid_list = ['xye','xyf']

for index,element in enumerate(s):
    for i in invalid_list:
        if i in element:
           element = element.replace(i, 'xyz')
           s[index] = element
    
print(s)
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 0):

`i in s` looks for an exact match, not a substring. And `list.replace()` also replaces an exact match, it doesn't replace substrings.

You can write a list comprehension to create the updated list. Move the code that replaces all the invalid strings into a function that you can call from the list comprehension.

```
def replace_invalid(string, invalid, replacement):
    for substring in invalid:
        string = string.replace(substring, replacement)
    return s

s = [replace_invalid(item, invalid_list, 'xyz') for item in s]
```